MongoDb $lookup through array and aggregate
Below are two collections orders and amounts. I have array of lookup data which is to be added using $addFields in orders aggregate pipeline and iterated and get total amount sum from amounts collections.
db={
  "orders": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "shopId": "s1",
      "consumerId": "c1",
      "dispatches": [
        {
          "_id": "d1",
          "status": "assigned",
          "toBeSentOn": ISODate("2024-05-15T10:00:00Z")
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "amounts": [
    {
      "_id": "a1",
      "shopId": "s1",
      "orderId": 1,
      "consumerId": "c1",
      "dispatchId": "d1",
      "amount": 100
    }
  ]
}

arraysElemsForlookup is the dynamic array of objects will be added in aggregation pipeline using $addFields and it will contain multiple ids for lookup from another collection.
Here below what I am trying aggregation pipeline but I am not able to access to through loop.
as arraysElemsForlookup  array of objects are added in aggregation pipeline and I want match
consumerId, dispatchId and orderId from amounts collection and show the total sum.
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      shopId: "s1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      arraysElemsForlookup: [
        {
          "consumerId": "c1",
          "dispatchId": "d1",
          "orderId": 1
        },
        {
          "consumerId": "c5",
          "dispatchId": "d6",
          "orderId": 5
        },
        {
          "consumerId": "c2",
          "dispatchId": "d2",
          "orderId": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "amounts",
      let: {
        arraysElemsForlookup: "$arraysElemsForlookup"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$orderId",
                    "$arraysElemsForlookup.$.$orderId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$consumerId",
                    "$arraysElemsForlookup.$.consumerId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$dispatchId",
                    "$arraysElemsForlookup.$.dispatchId"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "lookupData"
    }
  }
])


Mongodb Playground Link:  https://mongoplayground.net/p/_hyCAVT2hIb
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      shopId: "s1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      arraysElemsForlookup: [
        {
          "consumerId": "c1",
          "dispatchId": "d1",
          "orderId": 1
        },
        {
          "consumerId": "c5",
          "dispatchId": "d6",
          "orderId": 5
        },
        {
          "consumerId": "c2",
          "dispatchId": "d2",
          "orderId": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "amounts",
      let: {
        arraysElemsForlookup: "$arraysElemsForlookup"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $anyElementTrue: {
                $map: {
                  input: "$$arraysElemsForlookup",
                  as: "lookup",
                  in: {
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$orderId",
                          "$$lookup.orderId"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$consumerId",
                          "$$lookup.consumerId"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$dispatchId",
                          "$$lookup.dispatchId"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "lookupData"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$lookupData",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalAmount: {
        $sum: "$lookupData.amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      total: "$totalAmount"
    }
  }
])


$match : This stage filters the documents based on a specific condition.
$addFields :
This stage adds a new field to each document in the pipeline.
$lookup :
This stage performs a join with another collection".
$anyElementTrue and $map operators :
It checks if any element in the array matches the conditions. It takes the array of boolean values produced by $map and returns true if any element in the array is true.
$unwind :
This stage opens the array field and creates a separate document for each element in the array.
$group :
This stage groups the documents based on a specified key and performs aggregations on the grouped data.
$project :
This stage shapes the final output of the aggregation pipeline means what to show and how.


In the $lookup stage, use the $$ prefix to refer to the arraysElemsForlookup variable.

Use $filter operator to filter matching element(s) in the arraysElemsForlookup array. Use $ne operator as upper and outer of $filter operator to check returned result is not an empty array.


db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      shopId: "s1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      arraysElemsForlookup: [
        {
          "consumerId": "c1",
          "dispatchId": "d1",
          "orderId": 1
        },
        {
          "consumerId": "c5",
          "dispatchId": "d6",
          "orderId": 5
        },
        {
          "consumerId": "c2",
          "dispatchId": "d2",
          "orderId": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "amounts",
      let: {
        arraysElemsForlookup: "$arraysElemsForlookup"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $ne: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$arraysElemsForlookup",
                    cond: {
                      $and: [
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            "$orderId",
                            "$$this.orderId"
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            "$consumerId",
                            "$$this.consumerId"
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            "$dispatchId",
                            "$$this.dispatchId"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                []
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "lookupData"
    }
  }
])

Note that you can declaring the data in the arraysElemsForlookup variable in the $lookup stage without the need of $addFields stage that adding new field to all documents.
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "amounts",
    let: {
      arraysElemsForlookup: [
        {
          "consumerId": "c1",
          "dispatchId": "d1",
          "orderId": 1
        },
        {
          "consumerId": "c5",
          "dispatchId": "d6",
          "orderId": 5
        },
        {
          "consumerId": "c2",
          "dispatchId": "d2",
          "orderId": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $ne: [
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$$arraysElemsForlookup",
                  cond: {
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$orderId",
                          "$$this.orderId"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$consumerId",
                          "$$this.consumerId"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$dispatchId",
                          "$$this.dispatchId"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              []
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "lookupData"
  }
}

Demo @ Mongo Playground
